# How to use bazel to build with cppkafka

Tags: bazel

I am newbie to bazel. I read through doc and know I can retrieve package via http_archive and use it if it is already bazel project. But when I am trying to build with cppkafka, I am lost and don't know what to do to build it with my project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bazelize cppkafka and its dependencies (e.g. librdkafka).

*librdkafka.BUILD*:

```
cc_library(
    name = "librdkafka",
    srcs = [
            "src/configuration.cpp",
            "src/configuration.cpp",
            "src/topic_configuration.cpp",
            "src/configuration_option.cpp",
            "src/exceptions.cpp",
            "src/topic.cpp",
            "src/buffer.cpp",
            "src/queue.cpp",
            "src/message.cpp",
            "src/message_timestamp.cpp",
            "src/message_internal.cpp",
            "src/topic_partition.cpp",
            "src/topic_partition_list.cpp",
            "src/metadata.cpp",
            "src/group_information.cpp",
            "src/error.cpp",
            "src/event.cpp",
            "src/kafka_handle_base.cpp",
            "src/producer.cpp",
            "src/consumer.cpp",
            "src/utils/backoff_performer.cpp",
            "src/utils/backoff_committer.cpp",
            "src/utils/poll_strategy_base.cpp",
            "src/utils/roundrobin_poll_strategy.cpp",
            ...
```

In the *WORKSPACE* file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl", "maybe")

maybe(
    http_archive,
    name = "librdkafka",
    build_file = ":librdkafka.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "...",
    sha256 = "...",
    urls = ["https://github.com/..."],
)
```

Similar for cppkafka with deps attribute to librkafka